# Not able to install android application on emulator

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I was developing a “hello world” android application using intellij IDE 11.0.01 and android SDK 4.0.3.
I ran the application using intellij, emulator was launched but it was not showing my application. Android logcat was also empty.
I closed the emulator. Killed the process adb.exe from task manager.

Then I followed the following steps:
1.Copied the .apk file to android \platform-tools folder. 
2.Started the emulator from SDK manager. 
3.Open the command prompt and changed the path till \platform-tools folder
4.Execute the commands: 
      adb kill-server 
      adb  start-server
      adb install my_app.apk

I am getting following error:
** daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * * daemon started successfully *  ** daemon still not runningerror: cannot connect to daemon

I am using Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3.I am working from my personal laptop and I do not have any antivirus or firewall started.

Could anyone please provide me information how to proceed from here?

Comment: You don't have to copy your APK to a specific directory in order to install it.

Answer (score 1):

If all fails, you could try installing the apk using adb:

```
adb install <path_to_apk>
```

Execute that commmand in a command window in the same folder as adb.

Comment: I tried on different system with window 7 SP1 os and Eclipse 3.7.1 and now I am able to run the application..

Comment: Some useful points to remember:
While loading Android SDK tools and platform 
Open SDK manager and select toolsoptions:
In the misc select check box force https ://…to be fetched using http
Provide proxy server and port details if you are behind the proxy.
Always open eclipse.exe as administrator (right click on eclipse.exe and select)